# Computing GPA Using Letter Grade - SQL

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    SUM((Grade*CreditHours)/CreditHours) AS 'GPA',
    CASE Grade
        WHEN 'A' Then 4
        WHEN 'B' Then 3
        WHEN 'C' Then 2
        WHEN 'D' Then 1
        WHEN 'F' Then 0
    END AS GradePoint
FROM 
    Student 
    JOIN Enrollment
        ON Student.StudentID = Enrollment.StudentID
    JOIN Course
        ON Enrollment.CourseID = Course.CourseID 
GROUP BY 
    FirstName, 
    LastName,
    Grade
```

Can anyone help me? I have searched everywhere! The question I'm trying to answer is: What is the coumulative grade point for a student for all classes he/she has taken.

Comment: Pls let us know which RDBMS you are using : oracle, mysql, sqlite, ...?

Comment: Hint:  `SUM()` is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should aggregate by student alone, and then take the weighted average of your `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    S.FirstName,
    S.LastName,
    SUM(CreditHours *
        CASE Grade WHEN 'A' Then 4
                   WHEN 'B' Then 3
                   WHEN 'C' Then 2
                   WHEN 'D' Then 1
                   WHEN 'F' Then 0 END) / SUM(CreditHours) AS GradePoint
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN Enrollment e
    ON s.StudentID = e.StudentID
INNER JOIN Course c
    ON e.CourseID = c.CourseID 
GROUP BY
    s.FirstName,
    s.LastName;
```